# Make UIImageView act as Facebook Login Button

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, button, uiimageview

Within my `main.storyboard` I have a UIImage view which is just a generic Facebook Login Button. However, I am confused because using these generic steps

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var imageView = <# imageView #>
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,   action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
{
// The Action 
}
```

I am a little lost as to what `The Action` would be in this scenario as I need to link everything through the Facebook SDK.

Comment: have you installed FBSDK?

Comment: Yes I have installed FBSDK and configured my `info.plist`, additionally I have imported the FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit

Comment: use Custom button for your concept

Comment: That's sort of where I am stuck the documentation isn't necessarily clear on the steps

Comment: As stated in one of the answers, why are you using an image view as a generic facebook login button? Wouldn't it be better to just use a UIButton as FBSDKLoginButton?

Comment: I'm using an image view because Facebook button sort of automatically centers itself so I used an image view to be able to make the button off-center and in better relation to the other button which will appear on the screen

Answer (score 0):

In your imageTapped

```
func imageTapped() {
        let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        manager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], fromViewController: self, handler: { result, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("process error")
        } else if result.isCancelled {
            print("cancelled log in")
        } else {
            print("logged in")
        }
    })
}
```